# Why is this shortcode function returning the data in the wrong order?

Tags: php, function, plugins

I've been attempting to create a plugin that takes some ACF options page fields, and creates a shortcode which outputs an advertising code attached to an attribute within the shortcode

e.g. [awin id="top_banner"] would ideally return the code entered for that ID

whereas [awin id="middle_banner"] or [awin id="bottom_banner"] would return the code for each banner respectively, wherever the shortcode was found on the page.

I also added the ability to show and hide ads via an ACF boolean toggle switch.

The problem I'm having is that if an ad is hidden or the shortcode isn't within the page, it's outputting the return of this ID, but in the next instance of the shortcode (regardless of the ID)

**Example**

Say the "middle_banner" was hidden (or that shortcode didn't appear on the page) when you scroll down to the output for bottom_banner, you see the output for "middle_banner" instead. When you'd actually expect to see the output for bottom_banner.

**Update:** Oddly enough, the ID's are always correct (I've outputted this as the ID of the DIV within the return) and this always shows the correct ID from the shortcode. So it's just the returned ad code that is the issue.

[image: screenshot showing the correct ID but incorrect output within that div]

My code that handles the creation of the shortcodes is below - I hope I've explained it clearly enough, I've also included the full plugin code at the end of the question if it helps for context.

```
// THIS LOOPS THROUGH ADS AND CREATES SHORTCODE ID's within attributes / and assigned ad code to return

           // WP Shortcode to display text on page or post.
           
           // [awin id="top_banner"]
           function awin_func( $atts, $content = null, $tag = '' ) {

            if( have_rows('awin_ads', 'option') ):
               
               while( have_rows('awin_ads', 'option') ): the_row(); 
                   $embed_code = get_sub_field('awin_ad_embed_code');
                   $short_code = get_sub_field('shortcode');
                  // $short_code = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $short_code);  /replaces spaces with underscores from input
                   $is_live = get_sub_field('is_showing');

                   $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
                       'id' => $short_code,
                       'embedded_code' => $embed_code,
                   ), $atts, $tag );

                   extract($atts);

                   $output = '';

                   if($is_live == true) {

                    $output .= '<div id="' . $id . '" style="color:#a0a0a0; text-align:center;"> <hr><p style="margin:0;">Advert</p><br>' . $embedded_code . '<hr></div>'; 

                  }
                  
                  return $output;
               

               endwhile;
              

            endif;
         }
      

      // this makes it init the function after wp has fully loaded
      
      function shortcodes_init(){
       add_shortcode( 'awin', 'awin_func' );
      }

      add_action('init', 'shortcodes_init');

?>
```

Funnily enough, however, when you inspect the code on the front end, the id attribute is always been passed through to the div id within the output correctly. This is what's really confusing me!

Any help would be most appreciated

**Full Plugin code below:**

```
<?php
   /*
   Plugin Name: Keep Digital Awin Shortcode Generator
   Plugin URI: https://bitbucket.org/keep-digital/awin-plugin
   description: This creates shortcodes for awin ads so you can use them around the site
   Version: 1.4
   Author: Dan Eland
   Author URI: https://keepdigital.co.uk
   License: GPL2
   */

   if( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly


// THIS CHECKS ACF IS INSTALLED OR USES ITS OWN LOCAL VERSION
   // Optionally you can use below to check by plugin location:
       // if((is_plugin_active('advanced-custom-fields/acf.php'))|| (is_plugin_active('advanced-custom-fields-pro/acf.php'))):
           

           // Check if ACF Classes exists: 
           if(!class_exists('acf_pro') || !class_exists('acf')):
               
               // Define path and URL to the ACF plugin.
               define( 'MY_ACF_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'acf/' );
               define( 'MY_ACF_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'acf/' );
               
               // Include the ACF plugin.
               include_once( MY_ACF_PATH . 'acf.php' );
               
               // Customize the url setting to fix incorrect asset URLs.
               add_filter('acf/settings/url', 'my_acf_settings_url');
               function my_acf_settings_url( $url ) {
                   return MY_ACF_URL;
               }
               
               // (Optional) Hide the ACF admin menu item.
               add_filter('acf/settings/show_admin', 'my_acf_settings_show_admin');
               function my_acf_settings_show_admin( $show_admin ) {
                   return false;
               }
               
          endif;


//THIS ADDS A PLUGIN OPTIONS PAGE
   if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
      
      acf_add_options_page(array(
         'page_title'   => 'AWIN Ads Shortcode Generator',
         'menu_title'   => 'AWIN Ads Shortcode',
         'menu_slug'    => 'awin-ads-generator',
         'capability'   => 'edit_posts',
         'redirect'     => true
      ));
   }



// adds custom fields to options page
            if( function_exists('acf_add_local_field_group') ):

   acf_add_local_field_group(array(
      'key' => 'group_625809450c759',
      'title' => 'AWIN Shortcode Generator',
      'fields' => array(
         array(
            'key' => 'field_625809567e7ec',
            'label' => 'AWIN ads',
            'name' => 'awin_ads',
            'type' => 'repeater',
            'instructions' => 'Create your AWIN ad \'areas\' here. You can create as many ad \'areas\' as you require throughout the site. When you want to embed your ad \'area\' in the site, simply place your shortcode anywhere on your site within a \'text\' container, and drop the AWIN embed code into the embed code field. 
   You can update the ad code within any \'area\' by simply pasting new AWIN ad code into the embed field for that \'area\'
   You can also hide the ad \'areas\' if you\'re between ads by using the show/hide toggle on the ad \'area\'',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array(
               'width' => '',
               'class' => '',
               'id' => '',
            ),
            'collapsed' => '',
            'min' => 0,
            'max' => 0,
            'layout' => 'table',
            'button_label' => '',
            'sub_fields' => array(
               array(
                  'key' => 'field_625809827e7ed',
                  'label' => 'AWIN Ad Embed Code',
                  'name' => 'awin_ad_embed_code',
                  'type' => 'textarea',
                  'instructions' => 'please paste in the Ad code from AWIN directly in here',
                  'required' => 1,
                  'conditional_logic' => 0,
                  'wrapper' => array(
                     'width' => '55',
                     'class' => '',
                     'id' => '',
                  ),
                  'default_value' => '',
                  'placeholder' => '',
                  'maxlength' => '',
                  'rows' => '',
                  'new_lines' => '',
               ),
               array(
                  'key' => 'field_625809c77e7ee',
                  'label' => 'Ad Area Name',
                  'name' => 'shortcode',
                  'type' => 'text',
                  'instructions' => 'What you\'d like to call your AWIN Ad Area e.g. calling it top_banner would result in creating the following shortcode: [awin id="top_banner"]',
                  'required' => 1,
                  'conditional_logic' => 0,
                  'wrapper' => array(
                     'width' => '30',
                     'class' => '',
                     'id' => '',
                  ),
                  'default_value' => '',
                  'placeholder' => 'e.g. top_banner',
                  'prepend' => '[awin id="',
                  'append' => '"]',
                  'maxlength' => '',
               ),
               array(
                  'key' => 'field_625819ba74b72',
                  'label' => 'Show / Hide Ad Area',
                  'name' => 'is_showing',
                  'type' => 'true_false',
                  'instructions' => '',
                  'required' => 0,
                  'conditional_logic' => 0,
                  'wrapper' => array(
                     'width' => '15',
                     'class' => '',
                     'id' => '',
                  ),
                  'message' => '',
                  'default_value' => 0,
                  'ui' => 1,
                  'ui_on_text' => 'Ad Live',
                  'ui_off_text' => 'Ad Hidden',
               ),
            ),
         ),
      ),
      'location' => array(
         array(
            array(
               'param' => 'options_page',
               'operator' => '==',
               'value' => 'awin-ads-generator',
            ),
         ),
      ),
      'menu_order' => 0,
      'position' => 'normal',
      'style' => 'default',
      'label_placement' => 'top',
      'instruction_placement' => 'label',
      'hide_on_screen' => '',
      'active' => true,
      'description' => '',
      'show_in_rest' => 0,
   ));

   endif;      


// THIS LOOPS THROUGH ADS AND CREATES SHORTCODE ID's within attributes / and assigned ad code to return

           // WP Shortcode to display text on page or post.
           
           // [awin id="top_banner"]
           function awin_func( $atts, $content = null, $tag = '' ) {

            if( have_rows('awin_ads', 'option') ):
               
               while( have_rows('awin_ads', 'option') ): the_row(); 
                   $embed_code = get_sub_field('awin_ad_embed_code');
                   $short_code = get_sub_field('shortcode');
                  // $short_code = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $short_code);  /replaces spaces with underscores from input
                   $is_live = get_sub_field('is_showing');

                   $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
                       'id' => $short_code,
                       'embedded_code' => $embed_code,
                   ), $atts, $tag );

                   extract($atts);

                   $output = '';

                   if($is_live == true) {

                    $output .= '<div id="' . $id . '" style="color:#a0a0a0; text-align:center;"> <hr><p style="margin:0;">Advert</p><br>' . $embedded_code . '<hr></div>'; 

                  }
                  
                  return $output;
               

               endwhile;
              

            endif;
         }
      

      // this makes it init the function after wp has fully loaded
      
      function shortcodes_init(){
       add_shortcode( 'awin', 'awin_func' );
      }

      add_action('init', 'shortcodes_init');

?>
```

Comment: Arranging elements visually in an HTML document has nothing todo with PHP.

Comment: Hi Honk der Hase, Could you clarify further what you mean please? perhaps I've either not explained my issue well enough or you've misunderstood? My issue isn't with layout, it's the outputs from the function arriving within the wrong shortcode placeholder, which would be to do with the PHP not the HTML. I've had 2 devs look at it (in my town) I'm just opening it up to the wider community as they couldn't see anything immediately wrong with what i'd written.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood it... If, like you say, all your PHP output arrives properly in the browser, have you considered the javascript part (the one that rotates the ads, if there is such thing)? Maybe it decides - even though `$is_live = true` - to not show the ad, but the next one? And by this, your logic gets incorrect? Very hard to say from the distance without knowing the entire system, but your problem _might_ be related to the frontend and not the backend really (guess that's what I wanted to say in the first place :))

Comment: Cheers, there's no logic to rotate the ads throughout the site - basically it's a way for them to be able to create advertising 'placeholders' i.e the shortcode at varying points through the site and to give them ID's. all the plugin is meant to do, is grab their input for that specific 'placeholder' and output it in place of the shortcode whereveer it is used on the site. currently it's displaying the output, but it's not linked to the placeholder ID, and is just appearing each shortcode position in the order of the inputted fields as opposed to being linked to the shortcode ID attribute

Comment: and this shortcode ID is guaranteed to be unique? Have you debugged the frontend side, aka where the request is made which uses the information you have passed? I still believe the issue is on that end, not in the PHP. You say that the expected middle banner appears in the spot of the bottom_banner - the frontend obviously controls, where an add lands, supposedly based on visibility of the ad. Maybe you have an inconsistency here, like I assumed earlier (the frontend decides to not show a add which the PHP code had considered visible)

Comment: I've received some support from a great guy called Alvin at ACF, who's pointed me in the right direction.  It was the wordpress function that I was creating wrong - attributes are meant as defaults when nothing was specified, so it was confusing matters by just using those in order regardless. There's also now a break so it stops running once the data is found and output - if you'd like to see how it ended up working please see the answer Ive posted. Thanks for taking the time to take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Shout out to Alvin at ACF Pro support for taking the time to look over this and offer a solution:

He said "attributes are used to set a default value when an attribute is not passed as discussed at [https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API."](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API.%22)

He also has written in a bit of logic that changes the output depending on the ID, and then adds a break afterwards to stop the code once the data has been found.

Works a treat!

```
// THIS LOOPS THROUGH ADS AND CREATES SHORTCODE ID's within attributes / and assigned ad code to return

           // WP Shortcode to display text on page or post.
           
           // [awin id="top_banner"]
           function awin_func( $atts, $content = null, $tag = '' ) {
            $output = '';

            /**/
            $a = shortcode_atts(
                     array(
                        'id'            => '',//Default value when there is no id passed
                        'tag' => '',//Default value when there is no tag passed
                     ),
                     $atts,
                     $tag
            );

            if ( have_rows( 'awin_ads', 'option' ) ) :

               while ( have_rows( 'awin_ads', 'option' ) ) :
                  the_row();
                  $embed_code = get_sub_field( 'awin_ad_embed_code' );
                  //var_dump( $embed_code );
                  $short_code = get_sub_field( 'shortcode' );
                  $short_code = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $short_code);  //replaces spaces with underscores from input
                  $is_live = get_sub_field( 'is_showing' );

                  extract( $atts );

                  if ( $is_live == true && $a['id']==$short_code) {
                     $output .= '<div id="' . $short_code . '" style="color:#a0a0a0; text-align:center;"> <hr><p style="margin:0;">Advert</p><br>' . $embed_code . '<hr></div>';
                           break;//break after finding the data you are looking for.
                  }

                     endwhile;

            endif;
            return $output;
           }
      

      // this makes it init the function after wp has fully loaded
      
      function shortcodes_init(){
       add_shortcode( 'awin', 'awin_func' );
      }

      add_action('init', 'shortcodes_init');
```